# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'users.users_IDX1' -- PHP code won't pass to SQL correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting the error in the title and whenever I check my database(MySQL), the primary key increments but the emailAddress is set to 0 and the rest are set to null. I tried to change bindValue to bindParam, no luck too. I also printed out what I was passing through bindValue and it's showing as correct. I could not seem to find the mistake on this.

This is the mySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  userID           INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  emailAddress     VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
  firstName        VARCHAR(20),
  lastName         VARCHAR(20),
  phoneNumber      VARCHAR(10),
  storeName        VARCHAR(30),
  password         VARCHAR(255),
  shipAddressID    INT             DEFAULT NULL,
  billingAddressID INT             DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT users_PK PRIMARY KEY (userID),
  CONSTRAINT users_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (shipAddressID) REFERENCES addresses(addressID),
  CONSTRAINT users_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (billingAddressID) REFERENCES addresses(addressID),
  UNIQUE INDEX users_IDX1(emailAddress)
);
```

The error seems to be related to the last line?

This is the writeUser function:

```
public function writeUser($user)
{
    if ($user->id === null) {
        try {
            // Add a new user to the database

            $query = 'INSERT INTO users (emailAddress, lastName, firstName, phoneNumber,  password)
          VALUES (emailAddress = :email, lastName = :lastName, firstName = :firstName, phoneNumber = :phoneNumber,password = :password)';
            $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

            echo $user->email . "<br>";
            echo $user->lastName . "<br>";
            echo $user->firstName . "<br>";
            echo $user->phoneNumber . "<br>";
            echo $user->storeName . "<br>";
            echo $user->password . "<br>";
            echo $query;
            $statement->bindValue(strval(':email'), $user->email);
            $statement->bindValue(':lastName', $user->lastName);
            $statement->bindValue(':firstName', $user->firstName);
            $statement->bindValue(':phoneNumber', $user->phoneNumber);
            $statement->bindValue(':password', $user->password);
            $statement->execute();
            $statement->closeCursor();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $query . "<br>". $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, I did not have the strVal on there, I was just trying to see if I can convert it into string, if it would work.

This is where the writeUser function is called:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    $vm = new self();

    $varArray = array('email' => emailPOST('email'),
        'lastName' => hPOST('lastName'),
        'firstName' => hPOST( 'firstName'),
        'phoneNumber' =>  hPOST('phoneNumber'));
    $vm->newUser = new User($varArray);
    $vm->enteredPW = hPOST( 'password');
    $vm->enteredConfPW = hPOST('confirmPassword');
    if ($vm->validateUserInput()) {
        $vm->newUser->password = password_hash($vm->enteredPW, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $vm->userDAM->writeUser($vm->newUser);
        $vm->registrationType = self::VALID_REGISTRATION;
    } else{
        $vm->registrationType = self::INVALID_REGISTRATION;
    }
    return $vm;
}
```

This is emailPost and hPOST (these two are just for validation):

```
function emailPOST($param) {
return filter_input(INPUT_POST, $param, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

}

```
function hPOST($param) {
$sanitizedParam = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $param, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
if ($sanitizedParam != null) {
    if (!hasPresence($sanitizedParam)) {
        $sanitizedParam = null;
    }
}
return $sanitizedParam;
```

}

I am really confused why 0 is being passed instead of the emailAddress. I also could not point out where the problem is, I tried tracing it for days already...

Comment: The error you are getting, feels to me that the email address you are adding is already in the database. Because you have a unique constrain named `users_IDX1` on the column `emailAddress`.

Comment: Hello, I tried inputting a new email address to test it out but I am getting the same error. Unfortunately, since the emailAddress is being stored as 0 on mySQL, all the new email addresses I add, results to the same error

Comment: It should insert a new ID, because you have auto_increment. The only thing that I noticed, is that your table schema does not have a length set to the INT columns. Don't know if that is the problem?

Comment: Please remove the try-catch.

Comment: Hello, after removing the try-catch, I am getting the same error.

Comment: You need to show us your debugging process. What is `emailPOST`?

Comment: this is emailPOST:
 function emailPOST($param) {
    return filter_input(INPUT_POST, $param, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

Comment: `strval(':email')` makes no sense. That just stringifies the parameter _name_, not the value. But that's already a string.

Comment: hello @ADyson, I've removed this and I am still getting the same error. I only added this to try it but no luck too.

Comment: Here's an idea: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php says `Return Values:
Value of the requested variable on success, false if the filter fails`. False might show up as 0 in the DB, I suspect. What does `$user->email` actually contain when you echo it (as shown in the code above just before your bindValues)? And if you're going to validate the email, wouldn't it make sense to then reject the form if it fails validation? Instead you seem to just continue straight on.

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` returns boolean. So if you get 0 then it means that the email validation failed. However, it makes no sense to do it like this

Comment: Please do share more debugging details, like from emailPOST, what is that value of those variables?  You can (if needed) anonymize it by changing every letter to an 'x' (but do not change other characters!).

Comment: Remove that `<column name> = ` nonsense in the `VALUES` clause (unless you really want the Boolean `=` operation there (but then you'd need to define the variables)).

Comment: Why are you using `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` on the data going into the database? This will only damage your data

Comment: sticky bit makes a _very_ good point. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: I am voting as unreproducible typo due to many issues with this code.

Comment: @ADyson hello, when I echo the email, it prints out the email address I entered and not 0, which is why it makes me really confused on why 0 is being stored in my database

Comment: Well as has just been pointed out by sticky bit, everything you're inserting into the DB is actually the result of a boolean operation in your VALUES clause. Do the other fields contain 0s and 1s as well? Double-check your understanding of how to write an INSERT query, please.

Comment: @stickybit hi, is this in the mysql or in the php code 'INSERT INTO.."? if its in the Insert into, how will I bind the values without the column name?

Comment: Seems you don't understand how to write an INSERT. Study some basic examples. You already named the columns in the first set of brackets. You don't need to name them again. `INSERT INTO users (emailAddress, lastName, firstName, phoneNumber,  password) VALUES (:email, :lastName, :firstName, :phoneNumber, :password)` - once is enough!

Comment: @helloPurpleMingo: In the `VALUES` clause of the SQL `INSERT`.

Comment: @Dharman we were required in class to use those for validation and sanitization

Comment: Ok but sanitising is for _output_, not input. Perhaps you misunderstood that aspect of it, too. And there's no point in validating if you're not going to act on the results of the validation! If your email validation _did_ fail, you'd still end up attempting to insert `false` into the database, which I'd guess is not really how you'd want it to work.

Comment: But not like this. You should not sanitize input data. You should encode the data on output. Validation is performed using `if` statements.

Comment: @Dharman wouldn't hPost return a sanitized value of what I passed?

Comment: yes it would, but you should be sanitising only in appropriate circumstances where it _needs_ to be sanitised, such as outputting into a HTML page. (You wouldn't need that filter if, for example, you were outputting to a console, or a text file or something. https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php explains what the filters do.) Sanitising the input before storing it permanently distorts the original value, with no way to recover it. which is why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: It probably would, but you should not be sanitizing input data! Don't use this filter for input data. It is only for output to HTML

Comment: I removed the <column name> but I am still getting the same error. I used what @ADyson commented

Comment: Hm, if you used `INSERT INTO users (emailAddress, lastName, firstName, phoneNumber,  password) VALUES (:email, :lastName, :firstName, :phoneNumber, :password)` then it shouldn't be producing that error any more (unless email validation failed, which you state it didn't). Is it the exact same error about 0s? Or is it changed in any way?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm still confused cause emailPOST and hPOST was given to us to replace filter_input which was already there when the professor gave it. Its mainly for validation as explained in class which is why I get confused

Comment: Let me try using filter_input instead of email and hPOST

Comment: I removed the use of emailPOST and hPOST and I am still getting the same error...

Comment: `as explained in class`...then either it was explained wrongly or you misunderstood how to apply what you learned. It's pretty straightforward: validation filters are for validating _input_. You need to do something if the validation fails, not just continue anyway.  sanitising filters are for cleaning data before _outputting_, and only in situations where not applying the particular filter could cause a vulnerability. https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Comment: What confuses me the most is when I echo the value ( echo $user->emailAddress), it shows me the email but once I use it inside bindValue or when its executed, it becomes 0 on my database

Comment: Just to clean things up, remove all previous test rows and try again

Comment: P.S. When you say you `removed the use of emailPOST` ...what exactly did you replace it with?

Comment: @ADyson I replaced it with filter_input which was what the professor originally gave us

Comment: Well a call to filter_input can do many different things depending on the parameters. You mean the same call to filterInput which is contained within the emailPost function anyway? If so then there's no difference in behaviour (which is fine because the validation was a side point about the general quality of your code). Focus back on the db issue...did you clear down the old data as I suggested?

Comment: Hello, it is now working but I am still getting the same error although, it is not passing 0 to my database now. Thank you so much. I think it is looping somewhere in my code now so its reading that the email address is being added again even though my database is empty. Again, thank you all for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: the column name was the one causing the problem